# Configuring a service according to another service

Tags: laravel, service, laravel-5, inversion-of-control

I have a service named `setting` which fetches use's preference from somewhere. I need use it in configuring some other service. For example I need to get user's email address email host.

Using `'host' => app('setting')['email']['host']),` in `config/mail.php` file, 
does not work. It seems that the app() services are not accessible in that stage.
What is the correct way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change a config at runtime within a service provider.

Let's just use the `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider` which is shipped with Laravel. So in the `boot()` method you could do any changes to the config like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->app->make('config')->set('whatever.config', 'This has changed');
}
```